# Where is the best place to share RPI Image files?

Tags: raspbian

I have created a [Raspberry Pi CNC board/hat](http://blog.protoneer.co.nz/raspberry-pi-cnc-board-hat/) and I have an image with a pre-configured setup for it. I tried sharing it on Drop box but they have now suspended my share due to to much traffic. Is there a place where I can host a 4gb file that will deal with traffic and size like this?

Comment: For every project we opted - rather than having an image - for keeping a command history logbook which results in a (very basic) install script .  We always start from a standard raspbian image and run the script.  Every package, setting and custom scripting is done by just copy&pasting the logfile into the shell.  That leaves us with an easy to modify 10 KB install script rather than a 4 GB image file.

Comment: @EDP That sounds like a good idea (as long as the image you use is still archived on the www).

Comment: Similar to @EDP's comment above, can you easily determine what changes you have made from a base Raspbian install?  That would be a good start to putting together an install script.  I'm working on a project that follows this process.  Take a look at the bootstrap script for reference: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zymbit/zymbit-bootstrap/master/zymbit-bootstrap.sh

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with free image hosting services.  However, if paying for bandwidth is not an issue, you can look into Amazon S3, which will run up to $0.09/GB (costs go down as data transfer goes up, see attached image from the [AWS pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)).

[image]

You can also look into [hosting a web server at digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/) for $5/mo and that gives you 1TB of data transfer and additional bandwidth for $0.02/GB, which is more than twice better than AWS's best pricing.

Going Digital Ocean, you'd have to install a webserver such as nginx, and there are instructions for doing that on [Digital Ocean's page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts).  Once you have it installed, upload your file to the server and you're good to go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Digital ocean is pretty cheap and competitive against S3 in the 1TB range.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can compress it under 1 GiB using compression tools like `xz` or `Gzip`.

Here is a [reference](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32992/distributing-a-rasbian-image/32994#32994).

Alternative could be any other file sharing site. Try `Google Drive` or something similar such as `Mediafire` and numerous others, but I heard that they are having the same restrictions as Dropbox imposes unless you're a premium user.

I'm not sure if there is a file size limit on `Github` and you can upload about an 1 GiB file on it but worth a try.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will give it a try. I used an 4gb SD card to make it and did not expand the partition but in the end I could not get is smaller than about +3Gb after using 7zip on windows..

Comment: @BertusKruger I have personally used rar and selected the most optimised compression option and made a 4 GiB card image in about 1 GiB. I assume that xz or gunzip would achieve even more compression. The only downside is you will need some extra time to uncompress it depending on how compressed it is. But I guess that's irrelevant in this case. Hope it helps.

Comment: Github have [Large File Support - LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) now, but they also start charging after allot of traffic.